# Best way to handle multitenancy in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant, cancan

I'm building multi-tenant application.

All data isolation is done by TenantID column in each table.

What is the best way to automatically handle multi-tenancy for all tenant models.

Example:

```
Contacts.new({.....}) should automatically add :tenant => curret_user.tenant
Contacts.where({....}) should also add :tenant => curret_user.tenant
```

Currently I see something like this in CanCan gem which that can fetch records for specific user parameters. But it is not providing anything for insert and update operation. Or may be I doesn't understand how to do it.

Regards,
Alexey Zakharov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you will work with all collections through tenant object.

Here is sample using Mongoid:

```
#Find all products with price > 500 in current tenant scope

current_tenant.products.where(:price.gt => 500) 

#It also work for create and save operations

current_tenant.products.create :name => "apple", :price => 200
```

Comment: Did you use the multitenant gem to accomplish this?  I'm trying to figure out how to assign a new tenant object during registration with devise.  Can you help?

Comment: @Nathan did you manage to solve your issue? I'm facing the same issue on login, because the current_tenant is not set at this point and yields invalid credentials error

Comment: @scanales I ended up scoping each of my queries to the current_tenant. There are gems out there that will do model level call backs, so it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I found out it was just a matter of calling `scope_current_tenant` at the very top of `ApplicationController` so that it was properly set before every other callback @Nathan

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out the multitenant ruby gem.  It makes it trivial to ensure that all queries performed respect the current tenant.
http://blog.codecrate.com/2011/03/multitenant-locking-down-your-app-and.html

ex:

```
Multitenant.with_tenant current_tenant do
  # queries within this block are automatically
  # scoped to the current tenant
  User.all

  # records created within this block are
  # automatically assigned to the current tenant
  User.create :name => 'Bob'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I Used **Act As Tenant** gem for multitenancy . It's pretty good gem and very easy to use. Here is a documentation of this gem [Act As Tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant)