# How many domains I can add to my app?

Tags: heroku

I'm planning app, that needs to have hundreds (maybe thousands) of domain attached. Is it possible with Heroku?

Comment: offtopic, perhaps you should ask heroku

Comment: came here from link posted there

Comment: hmmm, odd,  problem is, its not a programming question.  Do they have their own forums?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know... Came here from link on this page: https://help.heroku.com/ (Ask the community)

Comment: I need multi tenancy support for my app and so I try to understand could I use Heroku or should rent VDS.

Comment: perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916625/writing-a-multi-tenant-rails-3-app-for-deployment-on-heroku

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no limit on the number of domains. However, if the number of domains starts to increase to more than a 10/20 domains, then you may consider to use a [wildcard domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#wildcard-domains) and handle the routing logic inside your application.

Comment: I read that article, as I understood, wildcard domain concerns subdomains and I need exactly new domains (I'm designing online store service).

Answer (score 0):

You can add any number of domains to a single app by repeating the add command with different values

Comment: And can I add DNS zone for each domain by my Rails app?

Comment: As far as I know, you must configure your DNS to point your application hostnames to Heroku manually, so you should have your own DNS to do this (it is not a job for Rails app)

Comment: Well, as I suppose to know all I need to create a new zone is to make changes in several text files (so why it is not job for Rails?), the question is: would Heroku provide me access to these or not.

Comment: DNS translates easily memorised domain names to the numerical IP addresses needed for the purpose of locating computer services and devices worldwide. You can manage you DNS with a Rails app (f.e. PowerDNS on Rails). But you still need to have it. In fact there is no DNS included to dino where you deployed a Rails app at Heroku. When an app has a custom domain assigned and your DNS is configured to point at Heroku, the routing mesh will take each request to the custom domain and route it to the assigned app